# Chemical symbols for the order of a rotational axis

Tags: symbols, chemistry

I need the following symbols for a class in crystallography, are there any package that contains them?

They are mostly needed for drawing figures in tikz as the numeral descriptions on the left will be used in text.

I have not been able to find them on detexify, nor by googeling.

[image: Symols for the order of chemical rotation axis]

Comment: There is information here: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cryst

Comment: thanks Sandy G, this is exactly what i needed. Couldyou write as an answer, so i can say you answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ul­rich Müller maintains a font package `cryst` for graph­i­cal sym­bols used in crys­tal­log­ra­phy, licensed under The LaTeX Project Public Li­cense.

The files `cryst.mf`, `cryst.tfm`, `cryst.afm`, and `cryst.pfb` produce the
graphical symbols used in crystallography to designate symmetry
elements such as rotation axes, screw axes etc. (cf. International
Tables for Crystallography, Volume A).

`cryst1.pdf` contains a description (in German) and a listing of the
symbols.

Installation instructions and downloads can be found here:
[Direc­tory fonts/cryst](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cryst)